# WPF DataGrid custom sorting with some records locked

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, wpfdatagrid, listcollectionview

I have a WPF Datagrid with custom sorting implemented and it works fine. I need to lock some of the records in the collection to Top and Bottom (Top Lock and Bottom Lock). So when a particular record is Top locked, it should be the first record in the collection regardless of any value for the selected column(ie I don't want to sort those rows which are Top locked and Bottom locked). Here is my custom sort method.

```
private void PerformLineCustomSort(DataGridColumn column)
        {
            ListSortDirection direction = (column.SortDirection != ListSortDirection.Ascending) ? ListSortDirection.Ascending : ListSortDirection.Descending;
            column.SortDirection = direction;
            ListCollectionView listCollectionView = (ListCollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(Lines);

            LineSorter lineSort = new LineSorter(direction, column);
            listCollectionView.CustomSort = lineSort;

        }
```

where **LineSorter** is my custom sorter class with **IComparer** implementation. This works fine. Now I want to apply Top lock and Bottom lock to the ListCollectionView. I have tried the following code with the above, but it doesn't have any change(ie list is sorted based on only the custom sort column).

```
listCollectionView.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("TopLock", ListSortDirection.Descending));
listCollectionView.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("BotLock", ListSortDirection.Ascending));
```

Is there any way do this scenario or do I need to manually remove and then add the locked records. Please suggest..

Comment: you can create the three different collections and union it. one collection will have top lock, second have bottom lock and third collection will have rest all elements.

Comment: Change your `LineSorter.Compare()` implementation to always return top-locked items as being less than other items, and bottom-locked items as being greater than other items. I'm assuming there's a reason you can't do this though?

Answer (score 0):

Well. You can make this happen from your code.

Let'a assume

> ```
> The page size         = 10 
>
> Current page          = 2
>
> Collection name       = myItems
>
> First Item to display = initialItem
>
> Last Item to display  = lastItem
> ```

Steps:

- Sort the collection
- Take 9 to 16 items (8 items) from the collection
  (Because you are in the second page)

> initial item number = 8 x (Current page number -1) + 1 last item
>
> number = 8 x current page number

So:

> initial item number = 8 x (2 - 1) + 1 = 9
>
> last item number = 8 x 2 = 16

(now you have a subcollection of 8 items which are sorted)

- Add intialItem to the top of the sub collection

myItems.Insert(0, initialItem);

- Add lastItem to the end of the sub collection

  myItems.Insert(9, lastItem );